# How to allow only the input of numeric data to uitable and text box?

Tags: matlab

I have a uitable in main GUI that has "n" rows (the rows depend on the value that the user enters in a text box) and 10 columns. I require a code (something like a keypresskeypress event) that allows me to evaluate and discard the entered data that are not numeric both in the uitable and in some text boxes that I have in the main GUI. I do not know much about event management in MATLAB and I'm having a lot of problems with this.

My uitable is called ("TablaDatosElementos") and the text box that allows creating the number of rows is called ("NumElem").

By consulting the official MATLAB forum, there are users who tell me that I require Java components for the job (https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/editbox-data-input-validation); however, I do not know how to use these tools since I am a beginner in MATLAB.

I require that the input and recognition of characters be done immediately (as is achieved with a keypress in visual basic) and I require that they be only numeric characters, with a decimal point, with signs of + and / or -. I do not require anything else.

Comment: Is this a GUI in appdesigner?  you can have a callback for when your edit field is changed.  I also suggest that instead of a text box, you use a numeric edit field which will automatically make sure that only numbers are entered

Comment: Do you have any idea what the code might be like? It is that you already have many things and you do not get the expected results. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hello. Thinking about it, maybe I do not require that the validation be done "immediately", it can be given in such a way that when passing from one cell to another (of my uitable "TableDataElements") the validation action is executed, erasing from that first cell the characters that will not be numeric, and as I understand this can be achieved with the "CellEditCallback" function, but I do not know how to create that code. Maybe this way you do not have to resort to JAVA tools for code generation. Under this new condition I do not know if it is easier for you to help me with the problem. Thx

Comment: Yes, this would be the correct way to do it.  But again, are you using appdesigner to create your GUI?